# CButtonColumn, Visibility Nested Exception in CGridView

Tags: yii, yii-components, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I have currently created a CButtonColumn in my CGridView to display several options for related models.
Like this

```
'buttons' => array(
            'publish' => array(
                'label' => 'Publish',
                'visible' => '(isset($data->deutsch))?true:false;',
                'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/publish.png',
                'click' => "function(){
   ...
return false;
}
...
            ),
```

Where "deutsch" is the name of a HAS_ONE Relation,
I basically want to create a visible exception in a way where I check if the record exists firsts, then check a field in that record!
 so I tried to implement a nested if Statement:

```
'visible' => 'if(isset($data->deutsch)){if($data->deutsch->in_something==1){true;}false;} ',
```

But unfortunately it didnt work.
Should I just create a function and call it or is there a simpler way to do it?
I have been going around this for the last 2 hours....

any help, tips or advices are greatly appreciated :)
Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'visible'=>'(isset($data->deutsch) && $data->deutsch->in_something==1)?true:false;'
```

Should work for you, I've just tested this on a similar dataset on one of my projects.

Comment: Sometimes these things slip by me!! Thank you so much!!